# Elastic Search using AWS - cURL request returns a boolean (false) rather than json

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I have a Elastic Search instance on AWS (Amazon Web Services), all the indices are setup and the status is fine, when I run some tests using Kibana I am getting json responses as expected, however when I try to run this via my web application using cURL I do not appear to be getting any response except 'success'.

When I var_dump the response from curl I just get a bool(false) value rather than an expected json response.. Any ideas why this doesn't appear to return a json when using the cURL method below?

The URL (changed for security purposes)
https://search-myapp-text-search-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxjaa2h2t5q.eu-west-2.es.amazonaws.com/

// Kibana Console

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
  "bool": {
    "should": [
     {
       "match": {
       "text": "facebook advice"
     }      
    }
  ], 
  "minimum_number_should_match": 1, 
  "filter": {
    "term": {
      "accountid": "12"
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Within my PHP code in my application I am simply performing a cURL request as follows :-

```
    $accountid = 12;
    $queryArray = [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                "filter" => [
                    "term" => [ "accountid" => $accountid ]
                ],
                "should" => [
                    [ "match" => [ "text" => $term ] ]
                ],
                "minimum_should_match" => 1
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $query = json_encode($queryArray);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, self::$url.'live/_search');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
    $curlResult = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    var_dump($curlResult);
```

Comment: try with this parameters: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php#119059

Comment: @Edwin I already have curl_exec() setup

Comment: does your curl call a HTTPS URL?

Comment: yes it does.. i will post the url above

Comment: then try to use CURL with the parameters from above : `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);`